# What is the PHP's mysql() function?

Tags: php, mysql, function, namespaces, undocumented-behavior

I came across a weird error in PHP:

```
mysql()
```

I tried with **three** different setups, and each time declaring a function with this name and any or no arguments generates an error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare mysql()
```

Yet, I cannot find a function with such name in the [function index](http://www.php.net/manual/en/indexes.functions.php#refentry-index-for-m), if it really existed I guess it would have been [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql.php). I tried searching the web but the ambiguity of my search queries makes any info on this difficult to find.

Usefullness of having a function called simply `mysql()` aside, what is this function and why is it not documented?

---

*Possibilities I ruled out:*

- That it could be a class constructor *(there is no such class)*
- That the name of the module is the cause of conflict *(doesn't work with other modules, like mssql)*

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? In my simple test with PHP 5.2.x (I know it's old) I could define a mysql function perfectly fine.

Comment: Tested on 5.2 on a hosted server and a uni server, plus whatever version a friend of mine had on his WAMP setup (assuming latest stable). All produce the same error.

Comment: Yeah, ignore my comment. Turns out what I tested it on doesn't have mysql installed, so no mysql something would be defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just a non documented reserved word
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

checking the source code, i've seen that function is empty

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because its somewhat correct and made me look into the source code; turns out `mysql()` is an alias to `mysql_db_query()` which in itself is deprecated (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php).